# Ansible amazon linux Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, amazon-linux

I am new to ansible. Tried to configure it in amazon linux instance to learn basic things about ansible. After ansible installation i have created a ssh key pair using command ssh-keygen. Once it is generated I tried to run the command " ssh-copy-id localhost" but it ended with below error,

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Could someone guide me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh-copy-id localhost
```

won't work if you don't have password authentication enabled in the `ssh` server on localhost.

If you need to set up pubkey authentication without allowing password authentication, just copy the public key locally (since it is localhost):

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
# make sure the SELinux labels are correct:
type restorecon && restorecon -F .ssh .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Hey Jakuje, it worked. thanks a lot for the workaround

Comment: Please, take a time to review [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) section to understand how to accept the questions that solved your question.